# Eigenvalues of the $m^{th}$ power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory

Let $K$ be a commutative ring or field and $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(K)$ a general matrix. I am trying to establish a connection between the eigenvalues of $A$ and the eigenvalues of $A^m$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

So far, I've been dabbling with two big cases - when $A$ is diagonalizable and when $A$ is not. Of course, when $A$ is diagonalizable, we have that $A\sim D$, where $D=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \dots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}$, where $\lambda_i,~i=\overline{1,n}$ are the eigenvalues of A. It follows that $A^m\sim D^m$, i.e. $A^m$ has the same eigenvalues as $D^m$, namely the roots $l$ (in $K$) of $(\lambda_1^m-l)(\lambda_2^m-l)\dots(\lambda_n^m-l)=0$. This is where I continued with two subcases, namely if $K$ has and doesn't have zero-divisors.

If $K$ does not have zero-divisors, then $\exists~i\in \{1,2,\dots,n \}~\text{such that}~ l_i=\lambda_i^m$ (in $K$). This is mostly where I am stuck, I'm not sure how to determine the rest of the eigenvalues $l$. Any bibliography and ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to read this section of the characteristic polynomial article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_Ak , as it's related.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for $A\in\mathcal M_n(K)$, its $m^{\text{th}}$ power is also $\in\mathcal M_n(K)$ and by the fundamental theorem of algebra, its characteristic polynomial $\chi_{A^m}(l)=\det(lI-A^m)$, which is a degree $n$ polynomial in $l$, has at most $n$ roots in $K$ (exactly $n$ roots in an algebraic closure of $K$). So, if your commutative ring $K$ has no zero divisors, your argument shows that $l_i=\lambda_i^m$ are eigenvalues of $A^m$ (in $K$) for $1\le i\le n$ and since there can only be at most $n$ roots, you've found all the eigenvalues (in $K$).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas  I'm pretty sure your arguments are correct. Although, could you clarify as to why my argument $l_i=\lambda_i^m$ is enough to determine all of the eigenvalues of $A^k$. If $K$ has no zero divisors, it means that $\forall x,y\in K,~ xy=0 \Rightarrow x=0~\emph{or}~y=0$. Therefore, if there exists an $i\in \{1,2,\dots,n\} \text{such} that \lambda_i^m-l_i=0$, there is a possibility that $(\lambda_1^m-l)(\lambda_2^m-l)\dots(\lambda_{i-1}^m-l)(\lambda_{i+1}^k-l)\dots(\lambda_n^m-l)\ne0$. What then?

Comment: What is your definition of "eigenvalue" over a general commutative ring?  I can't think of any definition that would not be rather poorly behaved in the presence of zero divisors.

Comment: In particular, if by "eigenvalue" you mean a $\lambda$ such that $A-\lambda I$ is not injective, I would not expect there to be any remotely nice answer to your question if $K$ can have zero divisors.  In particular, it's not even true that if $A$ is diagonalizable then the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$--the diagonal entries are *some of* the eigenvalues, but maybe not all of them!

Comment: @EricWofsey well, by eigenvalue over $K$ I mean a root in $K$ of the characteristic polynomial attached to the given matrix (i.e. a solution in $K$ for the equation $\det{A-\lambda I_n}=0$). Although I'm not entirely sure, maybe I should try and limit my work in structures with no zero divisors? The fact is that I am trying to establish certain new (in a research sort of way?) results on this topic and you know how it goes, the more general, the better.

Comment: Really, the right thing to do is probably not to study actual roots of the characteristic polynomial but to instead study the *scheme* $\operatorname{Spec}K[x]/(p(x))$ where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial.  The $K$-points of this are roots in $K$, but those are badly behaved and I don't know why you would be interested in them.